# Regex replace pattern - PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need some help, I have a replacement pattern:

```
/(?<!\S)(\b|\(|\[)(?:\d+\s*x\s*)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*litres($|\s|\.|;|,|\)|\])/is
```

with function:

```
preg_replace('/(?<!\S)(\b|\(|\[)(?:\d+\s*x\s*)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*litres($|\s|\.|;|,|\)|\])/is', '', $string);
```

which replace to '' - empty string and in 99% cases works great, however there is some which are not working as exprected.

So i.e.

Bottle (blue, 10 Litres) - will be replaced to **Bottle (blue,** instead of **Bottle (blue,)**.

it looks like the right boundry {in example above **)** sign} is being treated as a part of the string to replace. Any ideas?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that backreference works: **${2}**

so i.e.

```
preg_replace('/(?<!\S)(\b|\(|\[)(?:\d+\s*x\s*)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*litres($|\s|\.|;|,|\)|\])/is', '${2}', $string);
```

should do the trick.

What you reckon?